# Not able to update data in MySQL using test class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, repository

```
@Test
public void testUpdateStudent(){
    Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById((long) 1);
    student.setName();
}
```

1. When I am using Optional I am not getting setName() method, how can I update record in my database.
2. Also, why should I use this Optional?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code? I don't see any code to save student to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getOne()`, if not willing to receive as `Optional`.

```
@Test
public void testUpdateStudent(){
    Student student = studentRepository.getOne(1L);
    student.setName();

    studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student)
}
```

There might be a chance of getting `NullPointerException`, when the record not present in DB.

When we use `findById(<some_parameter>)`, Spring Data JPA returns an `Optional` object. Can get the object after `isPresent()` condition satisfied as follows:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateStudent(){
    Optional<Student> studentOpt = studentRepository.getOne(1L);
    if(studentOpt.isPresent()) {
        Student student = studentOpt.get();
        student.setName();
        studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I am using Optional I am not getting setName() method, how can I update record in my database.

Since you are getting Optional, you can set the value in the following manner:

```java
@Test
public void testUpdateStudent(){
    Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById((long) 1);
    student.get().setName();
}
```

Optional.get() gives you the value T present in the Optional.

> Also, why should I use this Optional?

Honestly, this really depends on which type of Repository your studentRepository is extending from. You have a variety of Spring Data Repostories available like CrudRepository, PagingAndSortingRepository etc. You can arrive at a consensus after going through [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) official documentation.